# Postgres: Create jsonb object with given set of keys and a default value

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I am using PostgreSQL 9.6. I have an array like `ARRAY['a', 'b']::text[]` which comes from application code and is transformed a bit in SQL, so I do not know its length in an application code.

In a table I have a field of type `jsonb` which I need to set to a json object, where keys are values from the given array and the values are *all the same* and equal to current timestamp, i.e

```
| id | my_field                                         |
---------------------------------------------------------
| 1  | {"a":"1544605046.21065", "b":"1544605046.21065"} |
```

I am trying to find an update query to perform this update, e.g. something like

```
UPDATE mytable 
SET my_field = some_function(ARRAY['a','b']::text[], EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
WHERE <some_condition>;
```

I was looking at `jsonb_build_object` function, which is likely to help me, if I could transform my array, interleaving its elements with current timestamp, however I did not find a way to do this.

Please note, that I am likely to have hundreds of thousands of records to update, therefore I am looking for a fast implementation.

I would be grateful for any advice on this matter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=f2b5fed6ad094772fa2aafb5966b3524)

```
UPDATE my_table
SET my_field = s.json_data
FROM (
    SELECT jsonb_object_agg(key, extract(epoch from current_timestamp)) as json_data
    FROM unnest(array['a', 'b']) as u(key)
) s
WHERE <some condition>
```

1. For using the array element as keys for the json object you need to separate them by unnest. This creates one row for each element.
2. Aggregating the rows with `jsonb_object_agg(key, value)`. As key your are taking the column of array elements. As value the `current_timestamp`. This function aggregates into your expected syntax.
3. Putting this into a subquery allows you to do an update.